# How to calculate percentile?

Tags: education

I am reading a document issued by UK Gov about minimum salary for work visa, it is using word percentile, which I don't understand, Could anyone explain what would be the 50th or 75th percentile IF,

10th percentile = 24,000

25th percentile = 31,100

50th percentile = ?

75th percentile = ?

Here is the exact wording of the document,

> increasing the Tier 2 minimum salaries per occupation for experienced
>   workers from the 25th percentile to the 50th or 75th percentiles, or
>   other appropriate measure;

[Reference - Page 6, Point 1.5 - II.](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/437324/Call_for_Evidence_Salary_Thresholds_FINAL.pdf)

I am interested in job code 2136, you can see table in end with percentiles.

Comment: a $x$ percentile is basically a value such that $x %$ of data falls under this value.

Answer (score 1):

The $k-th$ percentile in a distribution I a value larger than that of $k$% of the population.

As an example, the $40$% percentile is a value ( a salary in this case ) higher than the salaries of $40$% of the population. The information you gave is not enough to determine the $50 th$ and $75th$ percentile.

As an example, if half the people make 30,000 pounds or less, then the number 30,000 is the 50-th percentile--meaning that 50% of the people make that amount or less. Hope you make it to Piccadilly!

Comment: Thanks Gray, Could you please tell me what other information do you require, I will try to find it, this is another problem I am not sure about, my guess is you want to know average salaries ?

Comment: so if the average salary of populatation (people in uk in a specific sector) is x, then percentile would be the percentage of this average  x ?

Comment: If half the people make less than x, then x is the 50-th percentile. If 75% of people make less than y, then y is the 75th percentile. But to know the values of $x,y$, you need more information. Example If 50% of people make less than, say 30,000 pounds, then 30,000 is the 50th percentile.

Comment: Sorry to tell you this, OT: these issues of immigration are so complicated that you may need to end up getting a lawyer or some other type of expert to help you. Hopefully there is a cheap one available.

Comment: ah i get you, thanks, please add your comments to answer, instead, I will wait for a better answer for few days, otherwise i will accept yours thanks :)

Comment: Just edited. Don't worry about it and wait for the answer you like best :) , and let me know if you have more questions.